# id passed is undefined, error 400 (bad request)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to remove the puzzle after answering it, so that the logged in user cannot constantly answer the same puzzle, the problem is that when it passes the id, these id is undefined. I don't know where I am making a mistake here is a piece of my code.
The error he receives in the console
Error: DELETE http: // api / Remove / undefined 400 (Bad Request)

```
state={
qBank:[{id:1,question:'dd',answers:['a','b','c','d'],correct:'a'}]
}
```

render:

```
 this.state.qBank.map(
                                ({ question, answers, correct, id }) => (
                                    <QuestionBox key={id} id={id} question={question} options={answers} selected={answer => this.computeAnswer(answer, correct)} />
                                )
                            )}
```

QuestionBox:

```
const QuestionBox = ({ question, options, selected, key, id }) => {
    const [answer, setAnswer] = useState(options);
    const [alreadyAnswered, setAlreadyAnswered] = useState(false);
    return (
        <div className="questionBox">
            <div className="question">{question}</div>
            {(answer || []).map((text, index) => (
                <button disabled={alreadyAnswered} key={index} className="answerBtn" onClick={(id) => {
                    if (!alreadyAnswered) {
                        setAnswer([text]);
                        selected(text);
                        setAlreadyAnswered(true);
                        fetch("http:/api/Remove/" + id, {
                            method: 'DELETE',
                            headers: {
                                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                                "Authorization": `bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem("access_token")}`
                            },
                        }).then(() => {
                        }).catch(err => {
                            console.error(err)
                        })
                    }
                }}>{text}</button>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: sorry typo I made here, the code is ok

Comment: So... The code you're showing us here *isn't* the code you're trying to correct?  Typos generally don't occur when using copy/paste.

Comment: I just wrote state by hand to show how it looks, it can help